# Why doesn't a particle moving at constant speed generate EM waves, if the solutions to Maxwell's equations in vacuum are always waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

I'm studying electromagnetism at the moment, more specifically Griffiths and I stumbled upon something I don't understand.

So, the solutions to Maxwell's equations in free space ($\rho = 0$, $\mathbf{J}=0$) are electromagnetic waves, represented by the standard wave function: $Ae^{i(kx- \omega t)}$.

Now, suppose a charged particle is moving in one-dimension with a constant speed $v$. Suppose we're interested in the electric field at an arbitrary point $\mathbf{x}$. We can choose a spherical boundary surface $\partial S$ around that point and solve Maxwell's equations with the right boundary conditions. Because of the fact that this domain lies in free space (the moving charge is not inside our boundary), the solutions must be EM-waves.

This is however not the case because the electric field of a charge moving with constant speed at a certain point $\mathbf{x}$ at time $t$ is given by the following equation:

$$ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)  \boldsymbol{=} \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{(1\boldsymbol{-}\beta^2)(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{-}\boldsymbol{\beta})}{(1\boldsymbol{-} \boldsymbol{\beta}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n})^3 R^2} \right] $$

with $\boldsymbol{\beta}  = \dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{c}$ and $\mathbf{n}=\dfrac{\mathbf{r}}{r}$

And this is clearly not a wavefunction.

How can this be explained? Is it perhaps that the solutions of Maxwell's equations in free space are plane waves and that every other function can be built by it by imposing the right boundary conditions (because the plane waves form a complete function space)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: a static field is a wave field with wavelength $\to \infty$ and frequency $\to 0$

Comment: a moving charge doesn't create a static field though...